# ##[error]Not found workingDirectory: /home/vsts/work/1/s/cd Frontend/Frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
  versionSpec: '16.14'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js 16'
- script: |
  npm install -g @angular/cli
  cd Frontend/Frontend
  npm install -g npm@latest
  npm cache clean --force
  npm rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
  npm install
  npm install --force
  displayName: 'Install Angular CLI and Node.js dependencies'
- script: ng build --prod
  displayName: 'Build Angular app'
  workingDirectory: cd Frontend/Frontend
- script: |
  npm test
  displayName: 'Run Node.js tests'

## If you have any deployment steps, you can add them here.

how to solve this, i want to build the angular with nodejs, during that it throughs this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build the node app with Azure DevOps pipeline, given your code is in Azure repository, You need to make use of [**predefined variable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) below:-

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

When I used my repository name directly without the predefined variable above, I received the same error code, Refer below:-

[image]

I used the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` that will read the source code from my Azure repository, As I directly have my app in the repository, without any directory structure like Frontend/Frontend I only used  `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` variable as working directory. ***In your case if you have a Frontend app inside a Frontend Folder, Add
`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Frontend` > `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` is your repository which will read Frontend folder, `Specify the internal Frontend folder with /`*** .

**My Azure repository:-**

[image]

**My YAML file:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build 
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    cd Frontend/Frontend
    npm install -g npm@latest
    npm cache clean --force
    npm rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
    npm install
  displayName: 'Install Angular CLI and Node.js dependencies'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- script: |
    ng build 
  displayName: 'Build Angular app'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- script: |
    npm test
  displayName: 'Run Node.js tests'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

#
```

**Output:-**

[image]